# Margin collapsing between tables

Tags: html, css

I have several tables on a page, and would like to have some space between tables. It is possible that some tables only have empty cells; such tables have a zero-height, in which case I don't want any additional spacing added.

Normally, margin collapsing would do the trick. However, I'm gathering that tables establish a block formatting context (BCF), and that margin collapsing doesn't happen between boxes that establish a BCF.

You can see this running the snippet below: you get a `1em` space between "1" and "2", but a `2em` space between "2" and "3", while I'd always want to have a `1em` space. But how to achieve that?

PS: Some constraints I have to work with: I can't remove the markup for the empty tables or add a class on them. However, I could add a container for each table, such as a `<div>`. (I was hoping that doing so and moving the `margin-bottom` on that container would do the trick, but it doesn't, maybe because if a block establishes a BFC, then its parents do as well.) Finally, I could certainly write JavaScript that adds a class with the margin on non-empty tables, but don't consider this to be an acceptable solution.

```css
table { margin-bottom: 1em }
```

```html
<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>2</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>3</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: one solution that is not supported is to use the `:has()` selector with `:empty` like this `table:has(td:empty) {display:none}` ... but this will probably work in 1 or 2 years

Comment: @TemaniAfif Right. But I'm not sure customers are willing to wait that long. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Not an easy one. How about something like this: https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/jQLWxL? The spacer is grey to show what's going on:

```
table {  
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

td:empty {
  display: none;
}

td:not(:empty) {
  &:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(99,66,33,0.3);
  }
}
```

You've only got one cell in each table in your example so this works.

Comment: Interesting, but, as you can imagine, the tables I'm dealing with typically have more than one row, with each row again typically having more than one cell.

Comment: Hehe. Yes, it also feels quite hacky but can work with multiple cells and rows by adding `tr:last-child` selector. I have modified the CodePen accordingly.

Comment: I don't mind hacky, if it works :). However, a `tr:last-child td:not(:empty)` would find any empty cell on the last row, so this will add a space if any `td` on the last `tr` is empty, while I want to add a space only if *all* `td` in *all* `tr` are empty. Plus `:empty` here isn't what I want to test on, as the `td` in general contain something, but that "something" might be hidden. So I really want to do what the margin collapsing does, but on blocks that contain a `<table>`.